# How to setup MySQL 5.5 replication using just SQL statements?

Tags: mysql, database-replication

I'm trying to setup master-master replication on 2 MySQL 5.5 servers using just SQL statements, but it doesn't appear to be working.

I've got 2 MySQL Servers on IP address 192.168.0.20 (Server A) and 192.168.0.5 (Server B).

On server A, I run the following SQL statements.

```
CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_HOST='192.168.0.5',
MASTER_PORT=3306,
MASTER_USER='root',
MASTER_PASSWORD='password-here',
master_connect_retry=6000;

set global sql_log_bin=1;
set global server_id=1;
set auto_increment_increment=2;
set auto_increment_offset=1; 

start slave;
```

The error log on Server A shows:

```
121029  0:36:01  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
121029  0:36:02 Percona XtraDB (http://www.percona.com) 1.1.8-28.1 started; log sequence number 1624076
121029  0:36:02 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
121029  0:36:02 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
121029  0:36:02 [Note] C:\Program Files (x86)\MariaDB 5.5\bin\mysqld.exe: ready for connections. Version: '5.5.27-MariaDB'  socket: ''  port: 3306  mariadb.org binary distribution
121029  0:39:05 [Warning] Neither --relay-log nor --relay-log-index were used; so replication may break when this MySQL server acts as a slave and has his hostname changed!! Please use '--log-basename=#' or '--relay-log=JoshuaNotebook-relay-bin' to avoid this problem.
121029  0:39:05 [Note] 'CHANGE MASTER TO executed'. Previous state master_host='', master_port='3306', master_log_file='', master_log_pos='4'. New state master_host='192.168.0.5', master_port='3306', master_log_file='', master_log_pos='4'.
121029  0:39:05 [Note] Slave SQL thread initialized, starting replication in log 'FIRST' at position 0, relay log '.\JoshuaNotebook-relay-bin.000001' position: 4
121029  0:39:05 [Note] Slave I/O thread: connected to master 'root@192.168.0.5:3306',replication started in log 'FIRST' at position 4
121029  0:39:05 [ERROR] Error reading packet from server: Binary log is not open ( server_errno=1236)
121029  0:39:05 [ERROR] Slave I/O: Got fatal error 1236 from master when reading data from binary log: 'Binary log is not open', Error_code: 1236
121029  0:39:05 [Note] Slave I/O thread exiting, read up to log 'FIRST', position 4
```

The error log on Server B shows:

```
121029  0:36:08  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
121029  0:36:09 Percona XtraDB (http://www.percona.com) 1.1.8-28.1 started; log sequence number 1623052
121029  0:36:09 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
121029  0:36:09 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
121029  0:36:09 [Note] C:\Program Files\MariaDB 5.5\bin\mysqld.exe: ready for connections. Version: '5.5.27-MariaDB'  socket: ''  port: 3306  mariadb.org binary distribution
121029  0:39:05 [Warning] IP address '192.168.0.20' could not be resolved: The requested name is valid and was found in the database, but it does not have the correct associated data being resolved for.
```

Comment: You're not using MySQL. You're using MariaDB, a fork. Should be similar but it's potentially important information.

Comment: Oh, I almost forgot about it as it is so similar to MySQL and worked with applications designed for MySQL, here's a quick list of differences, thanks - https://kb.askmonty.org/en/mariadb-versus-mysql-features/

Answer (score 0):

> Binary log is not open ( server_errno=1236)

It seems you have not started your master's binary log.  I suggest you stop the slave, and do a `slave reset` then turn on your master's binary log by setting your `log-bin` to the file that you want to use for the binary logs.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, this works but I'll need to be able to do it using SQL statement solely. Why wouldn't "SET GLOBAL sql_log_bin=1;" do the same?  See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/set-sql-log-bin.html